# Exoplayer 2 Player not resuming play

Tags: android, onresume, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

There is an issue with my player activity, which i cant resume play back.
Here is the code.

```
     public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, ExoPlayer.EventListener {

public static boolean incomingCall;
   //object of timer
private Timer mTimer_heartBeat;
//timer task
private TimerTask mTimerTask_heartBeat;
//actions in player
private String mStr_output;
//checking heart beat started
private boolean mBoolean_heartbeatStarted = false;
//exoplayer

public static SimpleExoPlayerView sExoPlayerView;
public static SimpleExoPlayer player;
private static DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;
private static EventLogger eventLogger;
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
static Handler mainHandler;
static MediaSource[] mediaSources;

static String mediaUrl = "";
ListAdapterDrawer listAdapterDrawer;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView lv_drawer_player;
NavigationView navigation_view;
SeekBar seekbar_player;
static TextView tv_start_player, tv_end_player;
RelativeLayout rl_infopanel_player;
LinearLayout ll_controlpanel_player;
Helper helper;
FrameLayout bg_black;
Handler seekHandler;
ImageView iv_arrow_player;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// Create a list to contain the PlaylistItems
//    protected static List<PlaylistItem> sList_play = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<MediaList> fullChannelList = new ArrayList<MediaList>();
public static int playerPos;
private String imageLogo;
ImageView bg_image;
boolean isLiveChannel = false;
private boolean isplaying = false;
Intent intent;
public static boolean isInPlayer = false;
private boolean isresume = false;
static Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    Constants.resume = false;
    intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getStringExtra("playType") != null) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra("playType").equals("CHA")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.drawer_player);
            isLiveChannel = true;
        }
    } else {
        isLiveChannel = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.new_player_layout);
    }
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         sExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_player);
    iv_arrow_player = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_player);
    iv_arrow_player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    });
    bg_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_image);
    bg_black = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg_black);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    permissions();

    if (intent.getStringExtra("url") != null) {
        mediaUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        Log.i("mediaUrl+-", mediaUrl);
        imageLogo = intent.getStringExtra("logo");
    }
    helper = new Helper();
    MediaController();
    fullChannelList = Constants.fullChannelList;
    if (intent.getStringExtra("playType") != null) {//for live channel
        if (intent.getStringExtra("playType").equals("CHA")) {
            if ((imageLogo != null) && (imageLogo.contains("fm"))) {
                bg_black.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                bg_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bg_black.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(this).load(FirtTimeParsing.imageUrl + imageLogo).into(bg_image);
            } else {
                bg_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bg_black.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            initPlayer();
            drawerSetUp();
            ll_controlpanel_player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else {

        initPlayer();
        bg_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bg_black.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_arrow_player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

private void permissions() {
    //set run time permissions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initPlayer() {
 //        sExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener((PlaybackControlView.VisibilityListener) sActivity_player);
    mediaDataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(true);
    mainHandler = new Handler();
    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    MappingTrackSelector trackSelector =
            new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    eventLogger = new EventLogger(trackSelector);
    // 2. Create a default LoadControl
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

    // 3. Create the player
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    sExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    sExoPlayerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    seekbar_player = (SeekBar) sExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_player);
    tv_end_player = (TextView) sExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_end_player);
    tv_start_player = (TextView) sExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_start_player);
    rl_infopanel_player = (RelativeLayout) sExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.rl_infopanel_player);
    ll_controlpanel_player = (LinearLayout) sExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.ll_controlpanel_player);
    seekbar_player.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    player.addListener(this);
    loadPlayer();
}

private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
    return ((BaseApplication) getApplication())
            .buildDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? (DefaultBandwidthMeter) bandwidthMeter : null);
}

private void loadPlayer() {
    if (!isInPlayer) {
        isInPlayer = true;
        sExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mediaSources = new MediaSource[1];
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(mediaUrl);
        mediaSources[0] = new HlsMediaSource(myUri, mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, eventLogger);
        MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
                : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);

        boolean haveResumePosition = false;
        player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveResumePosition, false);
        sExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        if (!isLiveChannel) {
            player.seekTo((long) Constants.seekto);
            updateProgressBar();
        }

        Log.d("Time==", "play time " + new Date());
    }
}

private void drawerSetUp() {
    listAdapterDrawer = new ListAdapterDrawer(this, fullChannelList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    lv_drawer_player = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_drawer_player);
    navigation_view = (NavigationView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    lv_drawer_player.setAdapter(listAdapterDrawer);
    lv_drawer_player.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (!mediaUrl.equals(fullChannelList.get(position).getMediaUrl())) {

                playclick(position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void playclick(int position) {
    isInPlayer = false;
    mediaUrl = fullChannelList.get(position).getMediaUrl();
    imageLogo = fullChannelList.get(position).getLogo();
    playerPos = position;
    player.stop();
    player.clearVideoSurface();
    initPlayer();
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        long totalDuration = 0;

        //sometime -ve value getting
        if (player.getDuration() > 0) {
            totalDuration = player.getDuration();
        }
        long currentDuration = player.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying Total Duration time
      //            Log.d("mUpdateTimeTask==", "totalDuration " + totalDuration);
        tv_end_player.setText("" + helper.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        tv_start_player.setText("" + helper.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int) (helper.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        seekbar_player.setProgress(progress);
        sExoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(5000);
        sExoPlayerView.showController();
        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

public void updateProgressBar() {
    seekHandler = new Handler();
    seekHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // Set fullscreen when the device is rotated to landscape
    //satatus bar color setting
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    bg_black.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //        sJwPlayerView.setFullscreen(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, true);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //satatus bar color setting
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    // Let JW Player know that the app has returned from the background JWPlayerView.onResume();
    //        sJwPlayerView.onResume();

     //        InitialDataFromServer login = new InitialDataFromServer(PlayerActivity.this);
     //        Constants.playerPosition = 0;
     //        login.PlayRequest(Constants.mediaId, Constants.start_play);
     //        loadPlayer();
     //        isInPlayer = false;


    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    isresume = true;
    // Let JW Player know that the app is going to the background JWPlayerView.onPause();
    if (Constants.isPlaying) {
       //            sJwPlayerView.stop();
        Constants.isPlaying = false;
        Constants.playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        isplaying = false;
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }


     //        stopPlayer();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    //            stopPlayer();
        super.onStop();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    stopPlayer();
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (isdirect) {
        InitialDataFromServer initialDataFromServer = new InitialDataFromServer(PlayerActivity.this);
        initialDataFromServer.login();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   //        stopPlayer();
    Constants.isPlayPressed = false;
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    seekHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    long totalDuration = player.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = helper.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
    Log.d("onStopTrackingTouch==", "currentPosition " + currentPosition);
    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    player.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {//for close this activity after finish movie
        Log.d("onPlayerStateChanged==", "STATE_ENDED==");
        Constants.playerPosition = 0;
        InitialDataFromServer initialDataFromServer = new InitialDataFromServer(PlayerActivity.this);
        initialDataFromServer.PlayRequest(Constants.mediaId, Constants.stop_play);
        isplaying = false;
        sExoPlayerView.hideController();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
        Log.d("onPlayerStateChanged==", "STATE_BUFFERING==");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isplaying = false;
        sExoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(5000);
        sExoPlayerView.showController();
    }
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
        Log.d("onPlayerStateChanged==", "STATE_READY==");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isplaying = true;
        if ((imageLogo != null) && (imageLogo.contains("fm"))) {
            bg_black.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            bg_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bg_black.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(this).load(FirtTimeParsing.imageUrl + imageLogo).into(bg_image);
        } else {
            bg_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bg_black.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        sExoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(5000);
        sExoPlayerView.showController();
        Log.i("Video_format++", String.valueOf(player.getRendererType(1)));
        if (!isLiveChannel) {
            setController();
            heartbeat();
        }
    }
}

private void setController() {
    sExoPlayerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                sExoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(3000);
                sExoPlayerView.showController();
                ll_controlpanel_player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ll_controlpanel_player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void stopPlayer() {

    if (player.isLoading() || isplaying) {
        isplaying = false;
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Constants.playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        Log.i("currentPosition", Constants.playerPosition + "");
        if (!isLiveChannel) {
            InitialDataFromServer initialDataFromServer = new InitialDataFromServer(PlayerActivity.this);
            initialDataFromServer.PlayRequest(Constants.mediaId, Constants.stop_play);
            if (isdirect) {
                initialDataFromServer.login();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
    Constants.isPlayPressed = false;
    isInPlayer = false;
    if (mBoolean_heartbeatStarted) {
        mTimer_heartBeat.cancel();
        mTimerTask_heartBeat.cancel();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

}

String motion;
Float x1 = Float.valueOf(0), x2 = Float.valueOf(0), y1 = Float.valueOf(0), y2 = Float.valueOf(0), motionX = Float.valueOf(0), motionY = Float.valueOf(0);
String xdirection = "", ydirection = "", operation = null;
int mScrenHeight, mScreenWidth;

public void MediaController() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
       //        heartbeat();
    mScrenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    mScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    Log.i("Display++", "Width: " + mScreenWidth + "\nHeight: " + mScrenHeight);
    sExoPlayerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      //                Log.i("event++", event.toString());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    if ((x2 - x1) > 0) {
                        motionX = x2 - x1;
                        xdirection = "+";
                    } else {
                        motionX = x1 - x2;
                        xdirection = "-";
                    }
                    if ((y2 - y1) > 0) {
                        motionY = y2 - y1;
                        ydirection = "-";
                    } else {
                        motionY = y1 - y2;
                        ydirection = "+";
                    }
                    if (motionX < motionY) {
                        motion = "vertical";
                        if (x1 > (mScreenWidth / 2)) {
                            operation = "volumeControll";
                        } else {
                            operation = "brightnessControll";
                        }
                        xdirection = "";
                    } else {
                        operation = "playbackControll";
                        motion = "horizontal";
                        ydirection = "";
                    }
                    Log.i("drag++", operation + xdirection + ydirection);
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("volumeControll")) {

                        if (motionY > mScreenWidth / 5) {
                            if (ydirection.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
                                if (player.getVolume() < 1) {
                                    player.setVolume((float) (player.getVolume() + 0.1));
                                }

                            } else {
                                if (player.getVolume() > 0) {
                                    player.setVolume((float) (player.getVolume() - 0.1));
                                }
                            }
                            Log.i("drag++", "volume:" + player.getVolume());
                        }
                    } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("brightnessControll")) {
                        if (motionY > mScrenHeight / 5) {
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                            Float brightness = lp.screenBrightness;
                            Log.i("drag++", "Brightness:" + getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness);
                            if (ydirection.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
                                if (lp.screenBrightness < 255) {
                                    lp.screenBrightness = brightness + 15;
                                    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                }

                            } else {
                                if (lp.screenBrightness > 0) {
                                    lp.screenBrightness = brightness - 15;
                                    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("playbackControll")) {

                        if (motionX > mScreenWidth / 10) {
                            if (xdirection.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {

                                if (isLiveChannel) {
                                    if (0 < playerPos) {
                                        playclick(playerPos - 1);
                                    } else {
                                        playclick(fullChannelList.size() - 1);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (player.getCurrentPosition() < (player.getDuration() - 10000)) {
                                        player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() + 10000);
                                    } else {
                                        player.seekTo(player.getDuration() - 1000);
                                    }
                                }


                            } else {
                                if (isLiveChannel) {
                                    if (playerPos < fullChannelList.size() - 1) {
                                        playclick(playerPos + 1);
                                    } else {
                                        playclick(0);
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    if (player.getCurrentPosition() > 10000) {
                                        player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() - 10000);
                                    } else {
                                        player.seekTo(100);
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void heartbeat() {
    int delay = 30; // delay for 0.03 sec.
    int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec.
    mTimer_heartBeat = new Timer();
    mTimerTask_heartBeat = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBoolean_heartbeatStarted = true;
            Log.d("heartbeat==", "heartbeat");
            Constants.playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            if (isplaying) {
                InitialDataFromServer login = new InitialDataFromServer(PlayerActivity.this);
                login.PlayRequest(Constants.mediaId, Constants.heartbeat);

            }
        }
    };
    mTimer_heartBeat.schedule(mTimerTask_heartBeat, delay, period); // 10000 is time in ms
}


    }
```

Player is working fine. But when the device locks and activity resumes the player is not resuming the playback.Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing on resume with the below code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
//satatus bar color setting
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
if (isresume) {
        isresume=false;
        player.stop();
        player.clearVideoSurface();
        isInPlayer = false;
        seekto = Constants.playerPosition;
        initPlayer();
        loadPlayer();

    } else {
        loadPlayer();
    }
super.onResume();

}
```